# How can I get ImageRender to take a photo from a camera and save it to a file?

Tags: python, game-engine, camera

I would like to create a Python script that is called when I press some key while running in the Blender Game Engine, which takes a photo from a specific camera, and then saves this photo to a file (preferrably in PNG format).
The code I tried so far always gives me "None" as image. I guess that the image is calculated only in the next frame, but I also tried to retrieve the resulting image in the next frame, and there was also None in the image.
http://pastebin.ca/3184737